# How to fix cross-site origin policy for server and web-site

Tags: google-compute-engine, dropwizard, cross-site

I'm using Dropwizard, which I'm hosting, along with a website, on the google cloud (GCE). This means that there are 2 locations currently active:

Some.IP.Address - UI
Some.IP.Address:8080 - Dropwizard server

When the UI tries to call anything from my dropwizard server, I get cross-site origin errors, which is understandable. However, this is posing a problem for me. How do I fix this? It would be great if I could somehow spoof the addresses so that I don't have to fully qualify the resource in the UI.

What I'm looking to do is this:

$.get('/provider/upload/display_information')

Or, if I have to fully qualify

$.get('http://Some.IP.Address:8080/provider/upload/display_information')

I tried setting Origin Filters in Dropwizard per this google groups thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/ybDOTOxjlLI), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 2):

In index.html that is served by the server at http://Some.IP.Address you might have a jQuery script that look as follows.

```
$.get('http://Some.IP.Address:8080/provider/upload/display_information', data, callback);
```

Of course your browser will not allow accessing http://Some.IP.Address:8080 due to the Same-Origin-Policy (SOP). The protocol (http, https) and the host as well as the port have to be the same.

To achieve **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on Dropwizard**, you have to add a CrossOriginFilter to the servlet environment. This filter will add some Access-Control-Headers to every response the server is sending. In the run method of your Dropwizard application write:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter;

public class SomeApplication extends Application<SomeConfiguration> {

    @Override
    public void run(TodoConfiguration config, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "http://Some.IP.Address");    // allowed origins comma separated
        filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filter.setInitParameter("preflightMaxAge", "5184000"); // 2 months
        filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");

        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

This solution works for Dropwizard 0.7.0 and can be found on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dropwizard-user/xl5dc_i8V24/gbspHyl4y5QJ.

This filter will add some Access-Control-Headers to every response. Have a look on http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html for a detailed description of the initialisation parameters of the CrossOriginFilter.